# How to validate a list using PIG script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have List 1 with following schema

> {customerId: int,storeId: int,products: {(prodId: int,name: chararray)}}

Customer List with following schema

> {uniqueId: int,customerId: int,name: chararray}

Store List with following schema

> {uniqueId: int,storeNum: int,name: chararray}

and Product List with schema

> {uniqueId: int,sku: int,productName: chararray}

Now I want to search customerId , storeId and prodId of each item in List 1 with other lists to check the ids are valid or not. The valid items has to be stored in on file and invalid items in another.

As PIG is very new for me, I feel this as very complex to do. Please give me a good logic to do this job using Apache PIG.

Answer (score 0):

First of all load all your data think these as tables

```
cust_data = LOAD '\your\path\to\customer\data' USING PigStorage() as (uniqueId: int, customerId: int, name: chararray);

store_data = LOAD '\your\path\to\store\data' USING PigStorage() as (uniqueId: int, storeNum: int, name: chararray);

product_data = LOAD '\your\path\to\product\data' USING PigStorage() as (uniqueId: int, sku: int, productName: chararray);
```

You can check your loaded data schema by

```
DESCRIBE cust_data;
DESCRIBE store_data;
DESCRIBE product_data;
```

JOIN Customer and Store data first using uniqueId (we are doing a equijoin)

```
cust_store_join = JOIN cust_data BY uniqueId, store_data BY uniqueId;
```

then Generate your columns

```
cust_store = FOREACH cust_store_join GENERATE cust_data::uniqueId as uniqueId, cust_data::customerId as customerId, cust_data::name as cust_name, store_data::storeNum as storeNum, store_data::name as store_name;
```

Now JOIN customer store and product using uniqueId (we are doing a equijoin)

```
cust_store_product_join = JOIN cust_store BY uniqueId, product_data BY uniqueId;
```

finally generate all your desired columns

```
customer_store_product = FOREACH cust_store_product_join GENERATE cust_store::uniqueId as uniqueId, cust_store::customerId as customerId, cust_store::cust_name as cust_name, cust_store::storeNum as storeNum, product_data::sku as sku, product_data::productName as productName;
```

now store your desired columns in your local /hdfs directory
below store command will store all the matching uniqueId from all three tables i.e., customer, store, product

```
STORE customer_store_product INTO '\your\output\path' USING PigStorage(',');
```

Similarly you can join your list1 schema and generate columns and store data using same logic.
Hope this helps